# jquery use of parseFloat and toFixed

Tags: jquery, parsefloat, tofixed

This works :

```
var x = parseFloat($(this).val());
$(this).val(x.toFixed(2));
```

and not this :

```
$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val())).toFixed(2);
```

I get "toFixed is not a function".

I don't understand why !

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are applying `toFixed` on jQuery object and not the value. Just shift it inside one parenthesis.

```
$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
```

Splitting up code to simpler and more understandable syntax is always a great idea though. Use a code minifier to take care of the build size.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write this is with `val(function)`

```
$(this).val(function(_, currVal){
    return parseFloat(currVal).toFixed(2);
});
```

Your problem in second version is the chaining is incorrect

Comment: $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
runs. If I well understand your answer, it's better to write this code on two lines ?